# URL for managing the security of a folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, folder

Is there a way to generate the URL for the page where you can manage the security of a folder?

Comment: You mean the permission page you can open from the List Settings?

Comment: Yes, that's the permission page for the library though. To get to the folder permissions page you need to open Advanced options in the Share Options of that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you should create is of the following format

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/weburl/_layouts/15/User.aspx?List=LISTGUID&obj=FOLDERGUID,ITEMID,LISTITEM
```

In this URL you should replace

1. LISTGUID - with the guid of the list
2. FOLDERGUID - with the guid of the folder
3. ITEMID - with the ID value of the folder

You can use below snippet to get the GUID of a folder

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var folder = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("shared documents/test");
context.load(folder);
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    alert(folder.get_uniqueId());
}, function(){alert('Failed');});
```

**To get folder id**

```
var folderItem = folder.get_listItemAllFields();
context.load(folderItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
    alert(folderItem.get_id());
}, function(){alert('Failed');});
```

Comment: How can I get the ITEMID of a folder?

Comment: See my updated answer